# XSLT: removing "&nbsp;" tags from for-each/select

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've been trying to remove tags with just `&nbsp;` from a select.
Here is an excerpt of the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >
<html>
<body><p class="text">
  <br /><b>Header 2</b>&nbsp;
</p>
<p class="text">
  Lorem ipsum.
</p>
<p class="text">
  More lorem ipsum.
</p>
<p class="text">
  &nbsp;
</p>
<p class="text">
  &nbsp;
</p>
<p class="text">
  &nbsp;
</p>
<p class="text">
  &nbsp;
</p>
<br />
<p class="text" align="center">Header 3</p>...
</body>
</html>
```

My select looks like this, which gives me all the elements between two headers

> //*[local-name()='p' and following-sibling::*[local-name()='p']/*='Header 3' and preceding-sibling::*[local-name()='p']/*='Header 2']

Inside of this for-each I'm just getting the value-of "text()" for each one of the nodes. 
Output xml looks like this:

```
<mylabel>
  Lorem ipsum.
</mylabel><mylabel>
  More lorem ipsum.
</mylabel><mylabel>
   
</mylabel><mylabel>
   
</mylabel><mylabel>
   
</mylabel><mylabel>
   
</mylabel>
```

I have tried to add further conditions to the select, such as not(string(text())),  string-length(text())>1, text()!='', or normalize-space(.) != '' but seems like `&nbsp;` passes all these.

Is there a way of removing (not selecting) the tags with `&nbsp;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on your entity `nbsp` is defined, assuming it is defined as `&#160;` you could select the `p` elements not having entirely a mix of white space and that non-breaking space character with `p[not(matches(., '^[\s&#160;]*$'))]`.

At https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTz6 you can see that the suggested predicate excludes the `p` elements with only white space and that non-breaking space entity reference, the example simply does

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:copy-of select="//p[not(matches(., '^[\s&#160;]*$'))]"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

on your sample data and the result is

```
<p class="text">
  <br/><b>Header 2</b> 
</p><p class="text">
  Lorem ipsum.
</p><p class="text">
  More lorem ipsum.
</p><p class="text" align="center">Header 3</p>
```

If you check https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTz6/2 then you can see that the XPath selection or exclusion works with your edited sample and the entity declared, obviously if you include the full XHTML DTD which puts the elements into the XHTML namespace then the XSLT needs to be adjusted to take the namespace into account with

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="//p[not(matches(., '^[\s&#160;]*$'))]"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or, as said in a comment, using `*:p`.

The xsltfiddle will not work with XML and DTDs so you can't check it there, but inside of oXygen or with Saxon from the command line the suggestion should work.

Comment: nbsp is defined as <!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"> ]>
However, adding that condition returns no nodes (the condition without the not also returns no values). Using local-names() is also a requirement as this xml with pseudo-html syntax may have namespace defined, but it may have no namespace at all

Comment: You might want to edit your question and provide minimal but complete and syntactically correct expressions to demonstrate the issue and the code you say you have working and you want to extend, I think the problem about the paragraph selection or exclusion is solved with my suggestion. As for claiming that you need some `local-names()`, your example doesn't show any namespaces but is tagged as [tag:xslt-2.0] where you could aways use `*:p` instead of that local-name hack to select `p` elements in no and any namespace.

Comment: It seems like the problem here is that current XML doctype is <!DOCTYPE html
   PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" > and that definition doesn't have the nbsp defined in the same way (or at all). Oxygen doesn't complain about it, but select finds nothing. If you provide this doctype to the xsltfiddle example seems to also fail.

Comment: The xsltfiddle does currently not work with XML referring to DTDs, sorry about that. But the problem with the full XHTML DTD is of course that it puts the elements into the XHTML namespace so the XSLT needs to take that into account, I have edited the answer to show two approaches.

Comment: Thanks, I'm accepting this as your solution does indeed work :)